# Find n random points with a minimum distance r inside a 3D rectangular box

Tags: random, 3d, coordinates, point

I would like to generate the (x, y z) coordinates of n randomly distributed points within a 3D rectangular box. the points must have a minimum distance from each other.
I wrote a code but the points are mainly located near the walls of the box. 
Any idea for a uniform random distribution?

Comment: You said you wrote code, show it so that we can help you better :).

Comment: Check your 'minimum distance' value - if it's like half of your box size or bigger, you'll have your points near the walls. Also, what do you use for random values? You may have some nasty numerical/rounding errors. And give us some code :).